# Taking vanishing ideals of $\mathbb{C}^2$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ is surjective to $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

A friend of mine and me are currently reading through [Vakil's draft](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/)
and are having a hard time solving following exercise (s. 3.2.I in the version of 29.december 2015):

> Show, that the map
>   $$\phi: \mathbb{C}^2 \to \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Q}[x,y]\quad, \quad (x,y) \mapsto I(x,y):=\{p \in \mathbb{Q}[x,y] \ |\ p(x,y)=0\}$$
>   is surjective, where $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ is the set of prime ideals in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$.

We have managed so far, that it hits every maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]:$
Let $m \subseteq \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ be a maximal ideal, so $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/m$ is an algebraic field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and so embedds into $\mathbb{C}$. Especially we have images $a,b$ of $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Furthermore we have (because of the evaluation morphism) $m \subseteq \phi(a,b) \neq \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ and since $m$ is maximal equality holds.

Also the case $(0)=\phi(e,\pi)$ is shown ($e,\pi$ as any transcendental numbers).

On the other hand for prime ideals generated by a irreducible polynomial $p$ we have the hunch, that taking $a=\pi, b=\text{any solution of }p(a,b)=0$ should do the trick (once again $\pi$ as the transcendental number of your choice). Once again one can easily see, that $p \subseteq \phi(a,b)$. The problems we encountered here, are:

1. Is also $(p) \supseteq \phi(a,b)$ true?
2. Are these all prime ideals in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ or are there non-maximal prime ideals with more than one generators?
3. Is there a sensefull way to extend the answer to the polynomial ring with n variables (the maximal ideals don't care about that)?

I would be really grateful, if somebody can enlighten us.

**Edit:** The second question is partly answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284940/number-of-generators-of-prime-ideals-in-kx-1-x-2-x-n?rq=1) for the asked case (polynomials over 2 variables). It remains to show, that a prime ideal with 2 generators is maximal.

Comment: Your solution for when the prime ideal $\mathbf{p}$ is maximal or is the zero ideal is that in both cases the quotient $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/\mathbf{p}$ embeds into $\mathbb{C}$ -- in one case because the quotient is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, in the other because it is just an extension of transcendence degree 2. The remaining case is when $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/\mathbf{p}$ (or its field of fractions, more precisely) has transcendence degree one. Your hunch here is that this also embeds in $\mathbb{C}$, and you can do so by taking $\{x\}$ as a transcendence basis. Does that clarify the situation?

Comment: Yes, I think I can do it with that (one has just to be carefull, which transcendental element you choose, but else it should go through easily). Thank you. Seems also reasonable to me how to extend this to the general case $\mathbb{Q}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$.

Comment: How did you show that $(0)=\phi(e,\pi)$?

Comment: @TiWen We were just abusing notation here: $e$ and $\pi$ are just two transcendent numbers (well you could take $e$ as itself and hope that $\pi$ is transcendend over $\mathbb{Q}(e)$ or pick $\pi$ accordingly). Since they are transcendend by definition the only polynomial which has them as roots is the 0 polynomial (else $\pi$ would be algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(e)$)

Comment: @ctst https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2592500/fe-pi-0-f-in-mathbb-qx-y-implies-that-f-0?noredirect=1#comment5352539_2592500

Comment: @TiWen I hope your question didn't arise because of this :-). As I said, we are just taking $\pi$ as any transcendental number over $\mathbb{Q}(e)$, not necessarily $\tau /2$ (circumference thing). The existence was enough for us and follows directly from the cardinality of algebraic vs transcendental elements. You should not consider $\pi$ and $e$ from above as the constants $\pi$ and $e$ (I know this sounds silly). In hindsight I am sorry for our notation.

Comment: Thanks~BTW Have you completely solved this problem? I am about to ask the same question... Would you mind answering your own question below?

Comment: Sure, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Following anon's comment we solved the remaining case like that (PS: The first paragraph is mainly about transcendence degree 1):

Let $0 \neq p \subseteq \mathbb Q[x,y]$ be a prime ideal, which is neither maximal nor zero. We consider now the quotient field $K=Quot(\mathbb Q[x,y]/p)$ ($p$ is prime, hence we can do that). $K$ is a field extension of $\mathbb Q$ and because $p$ is not maximal it has at least transcendence degree 1 (else $\mathbb Q[x,y]/p$ would be already a field). Also since $p \neq 0$ we have an algebraic relation between $x$ and $y$, hence the field extension has transcendence degree at most 1. W.l.o.g we can hence assume the image of $x$ in $K$ to be transcendental over $\mathbb Q$. Hence we get the chain of field extensions (first purely transcendental, second algebraic):
$$ \mathbb Q \subset M:=Quot(\mathbb Q[x]/(p \cap \mathbb Q[x])) \subseteq K$$
We now identify $M \cong \mathbb Q(\pi) \subseteq \mathbb C$ for $\pi$ the transcendental number of your choice (and hence we also can consider $K \subseteq \mathbb C$). Since $M \subseteq K$ is a finite algebraic extension (and separabel), we have a primitive element $\zeta \in K \subseteq \mathbb C$ with $M[\zeta]=K$. So altogether we have a field isomorphism
$$\mathbb Q (\pi, \zeta) \to K \ , \ (\pi, \zeta) \mapsto (x,y) $$
Concatenating now the evaluation morphism for $\mathbb Q[x,y]$ at $(\pi, \zeta)$ with this isomorphism yields, that the vanishing ideal is exactly $p$, hence $I(\pi, \zeta)=p$.

---

Similarly (maybe nicer than the special case before):

Let $p \subseteq \mathbb Q[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ be a prime ideal and $K=Quot(\mathbb Q[x_1, \dots, x_n]/p)$, then $K$ is a field extension of finite transcendence degree over $\mathbb Q$. Hence there exist $t_1, \dots, t_k, \zeta_{k+1}, \dots, \zeta_n \in \mathbb C$ with $\mathbb Q(t_1, \dots, t_k, \zeta_{k+1}, \dots, \zeta_n) \cong K$ and as before the evaluation morphism now yields the desired kernel.