# $f(e,\pi)=0, f\in \mathbb Q[x,y]$ implies that $f=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials

I want to prove if $f(e,\pi)=0, f\in \mathbb Q[x,y]$ then $f=0$. My idea is to somehow convert this problem into the one-variable case. For example if I can show that $f(x,\pi)=0$ as a polynomial in $\mathbb C[x]$, the life might be easier (though I don't know how to continue even after showing this.)

There may be some famous theorem about the "chemical reaction" of two transcendental numbers, but I don't know.

Comment: It is unknown whether expressions like $e\pi$ or $e+\pi$ are transcendental.

Comment: You are asking whether $e$ and $\pi$ are algebraically independent. This is expected but it’s a wide open problem.

Comment: It is, indeed, an open problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_independence#Algebraic_independence_of_known_constants

Comment: Related discussion on MO: [Work on independence of pi and e](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33817/work-on-independence-of-pi-and-e/).